# Using InputBox for forecast sheet: simple code

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Sub forecasting()

    Dim rng As Range
    

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range to forecast on", "Forecasting", Type:=8)
     
  

' forecasting Macro'
' input "rng" from inputbox'

    activeworkbook.CreateForecastSheet Timeline:=Sheets("All Households").Range( _
    "A5:A14"), Values:=Sheets("All Households").Range( _
    rng), ForecastEnd:=2022, ConfInt:=0.95 _
    , Seasonality:=1, ChartType:=xlForecastChartTypeLine, Aggregation:= _
    xlForecastAggregationAverage, DataCompletion:= _
    xlForecastDataCompletionInterpolate, ShowStatsTable:=False

    
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Basically, I am trying to put rng as I have the year column fixed. However I get the error: application or object defined error 1004, and debugger points me to createforecastsheeet block. Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong with rng object or using the inputbox?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter expected where you're using `rng` at

```
Values:=Sheets("All Households").Range(rng)
```

is just expecting a string, not a range object, so just use a string instead:

```
Dim rng As String
    rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range to forecast on", "Forecasting")
```

Comment: Type mismatch even after changing rng to string whilst the debugger points to line rng=..., line. Strange.

Comment: Have you got the lines exactly as above? (i.e. there is no `set`) - are you on Mac or something? Debugger shouldn't be breaking for those first two lines, they're pretty basic!

Comment: windows. 

The only thing changed in code was dim as string and removed set. Range should be so darn easy which is really annoying.

Should I remove underscore on range?